# Gulp - require gulpfile from node.js and pass task data

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm trying to run gulpfile from another node.js file

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
require('coffee-script/register');
require('../gulpfile');
```

and execute it like:

```
node ./bin/runGulp.js serve --foo bar
```

Unfortunately it doesn't start this task.

Answer (score 0):

You should run gulp with `gulp` command instead of `node`.

Try

```
gulp --gulpfile bin/rungGulp.js server --foo bar
```

More: [Github issue](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/122) and [gulp cli docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/CLI.md).